# Output the index of map()

Tags: javascript

I want to output the index of each element using map().

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const div = document.querySelector('.container')
div.innerHTML = arr.map((index,val) => "<div class='it'>"+val+"</div>" ).join('');
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.it {
    border: 2px solid;
    background-color: burlywood;
    color: white;
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container"></div>
```

How to output indexes of each element inside `div.innerHTML = arr.map((index,val) => "<div class='it'>"+val+"</div>" ).join('');`?

Comment: Add the index to what you output.

Comment: You have the parameters of the map callback back to front. Value is the first parameter, index is the second.

Comment: @Dave Newton, how to output index as `class`? example: class="1", ...class="9"

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
// You can just fill an array with the required number of null elements
const arr = new Array(9).fill(null);
const div = document.querySelector('.container');
// Note that index is the second parameter of the callback passed to map
div.innerHTML = arr.map((val, index) => {
    const count = index + 1;
    // If you prepend the count with "it-", the class name is valid
    return `<div class="it it-${count}">${count}</div>`;
}).join('');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q823fan0/3/)

Comment: how to output index as class? example: class="1", ...class="9"

Comment: 1 and 9 are not valid class names. You'd need to prepend with a character which is valid for the first character of a class name. See update.

Comment: could you take  a look please, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345237/save-data-in-a-special-order-when-click-on-button, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the innerHTML while you're mapping through the values and use the += assignment operator to concatenate each value.

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const div = document.querySelector('.container')
arr.map(val => div.innerHTML += `<div class='it'>${val}</div>`)
```

Comment: This isn't right - the map in the example builds an array of html strings which are then joined and applied in one go to `innerHtml`

Comment: Actually, to amend that. What you've got isn't wrong, but it's not the solution to the the OP's problem. It's not necessary to apply `innerHTML` within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try to understand...
this ?

```js
const arr = [ 'a','b','c'];

const div = document.querySelector('#container')

div.innerHTML = arr.map((val,i)=>`<div>${val} - ${i}</div>`).join('');
```

```css
#container div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  background-color: burlywood;
  color: white;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.6em;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: could you take  a look please, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345237/save-data-in-a-special-order-when-click-on-button

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the following:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
...
div.innerHTML = arr.map((index,val) => "<div class='it'>"+val+"</div>" ).join('');
```

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) has index of the element as the second parameter. So to get this index, your code should be like:

```
div.innerHTML = arr.map((val,index)=>`<div>${val} - ${index}</div>`).join('');
```

This should solve your problem.