# Save data in a special order when click on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create an application where user can add some notes to a specific `car`  in my examlpe. User has to be able to add a comment and to rate the car.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ visible: false });
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);

  const showModal = () => {
    setState({
      visible: true
    });
  };

  const handleOk = (e) => {
    setState({
      visible: false
    });
    console.log("all data", myData);
  };

  const handleCancel = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    setState({
      visible: false
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={state.visible}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
      >
        <Data setMyData={setMyData} />
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

In `console.log("all data", myData);` i have to get the result.

Now i have this array of items:

```css
const data = [
  {
    cars: [
      {
        carName: "bmw",
        carSpeed: 100
      }
    ],
    carCat: "4X4 car",
    carColor: "blue"
  },
  {
    cars: [
      {
        carName: "audi",
        carSpeed: 150
      }
    ],
    carCat: "fast car",
    carColor: "red"
  },
  {
    cars: [
      {
        carName: "mercedes",
        carSpeed: 170
      }
    ],
    carCat: "confort car",
    carColor: "white"
  }
];
```

When user will open the modal, he will se 3 blocks of data, there he will be able to add comments and a rate.

 Scenario: In this way if user adds data in the `4X4 car` block (rate and comment). and after that saves the  data, clicking on `save` button, the array should change in the next way:

```css
const data = [
  {
    cars: [
      {
        carName: "bmw",
        carSpeed: 100
      }
    ],
    carCat: "4X4 car",
    carColor: "blue",
    rate: 3,  // depends by the user rate
    comments: ["user's text"] // depends by user
  },
  {
    cars: [
      {
        carName: "audi",
        carSpeed: 150
      }
    ],
    carCat: "fast car",
    carColor: "red"
  },
  {
    cars: [
      {
        carName: "mercedes",
        carSpeed: 170
      }
    ],
    carCat: "confort car",
    carColor: "white"
  }
];
```

If user add data not just for one block but for all, all data from array should change according to the previous way, depending by the user input.

Now i get just an array of data when i save.

**Question: How to implemement what i described above?** Thanks for help.
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-margulis-4yx9b?file=/Data.js:60-489

Answer (score 1):

To make your scenario working you should update `<Data />` and `<SetData />` components as follows:

```
const Data = () => {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState(data);

  const setRate = (category, rate) => {
    const newCars = [...cars];
    let index = newCars.findIndex((c) => c.carCat === category);
    newCars[index] = Object.assign(newCars[index], { rate });

    setCars(newCars);
  };

  const setComment = (category, comment) => {
    const newCars = [...cars];
    let index = newCars.findIndex((c) => c.carCat === category);
    newCars[index] = Object.assign(newCars[index], { comment });

    setCars(newCars);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {cars.map((i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i.carCat}>
            <span>{i.carCat}</span>
            <SetData
              setRate={(rate) => setRate(i.carCat, rate)}
              setComment={(comment) => setComment(i.carCat, comment)}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const SetData = ({ setRate, setComment }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Rate onChange={setRate} />
      <input
        onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="comment"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The most important part here is how `setRate` and `setComment` props of `<SetData />` component are passed.

```
<SetData
  setRate={(rate) => setRate(i.carCat, rate)}
  setComment={(comment) => setComment(i.carCat, comment)}
/>
```

---

**Update 1**

> How to create an array of comments, for example user add one time a comment and clicks on OK button to save, and after that again open the modal and also add another comment for that block, and in this way to create an array of comments.

Basically, you need to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) even further to `<App />` component. Use this example as guidance: [https://codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/public-antd-modal-n2uj7)

Comment: it is great, but how to create an array of comments, for example user add one  time a comment and clicks on `OK` button to save, and after that again open the modal and also add another comment for that block, and in this way to create an array of comments. Could you help, please? Thanks

Comment: i tried `newCars[index] = Object.assign(newCars[index], { comment: [...comment, comment] });`, but it coppy every leter as a single comment. How to fix?

Comment: i have a question, why, when i open the modal window and after that i type a comment, and immediately after typing the comment click on a star, the text disappears?Thanks

Comment: could you help, please?